# Create pivot table based on power pivot works in Excel 2013 but not Excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel, powerpivot

The code below works for Excel 2013, but doesn't always work for Excel 2010. It throws an error on `set pvtSource`.

The error is:

> The error quotes "Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108)': method
>   'createpivottable' of object 'pivotcache' failed. "

Sometimes it works without throwing an error. I can't figure out why or how to fail-proof this code.

```
'Create temp sheet
Dim wksSource As Worksheet
Set wksSource = wbkSource.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count))

'Create new cache
Dim pvcSource As PivotCache
Dim pvtSource As PivotTable
If Application.Version = "15.0" Then
    'Create pivot cache
    Set pvcSource = wbkSource.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlExternal, _
    SourceData:=ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ThisWorkbookDataModel"), _
    Version:=5)

    wbkSource.Activate
    wksSource.Activate

    'Create PivotTable
    Set pvtSource = pvcSource.CreatePivotTable( _
    TableDestination:=ActiveCell, _
    DefaultVersion:=5)

ElseIf Application.Version = "14.0" Then
    'Create pivot cache
    Set pvcSource = wbkSource.PivotCaches.Create( _
    SourceType:=xlExternal, _
    SourceData:=ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ThisWorkbookDataModel"), _
    Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

    wbkSource.Activate
    wksSource.Activate

    'Create PivotTable
    Set pvtSource = pvcSource.CreatePivotTable( _
    TableDestination:=ActiveCell, _
    DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14)

End If
```

Comment: I had an issue close to this in Excel 2010 too, I couldn't create an *unused* Pivot Cache, I had to do it inside a Pivot Table creation to then affect it to the Pivot Cache variable via `Set pvcSource = pvtSource.PivotCache`. Hope this help! (a useful link too, but you might know it : https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Upgrade-Power-Pivot-Data-Models-to-Excel-2013-c66578cb-74d5-43ae-a474-5a01be5db439#__what_s_different_in)

Comment: My bad, it was changing the pivot cache of a pivot table with a newly created cache and then store it to assign it to others! Let me know if it helped you! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Power Pivot for Excel 2010 is explicitly not supported for VBA scripting.

Answer (score 1):

Here the Pivot Cache is created from the Range named `Named_Range` in the Sheet named `Sheet_Name`, I leave it to you to rename these to fit your need! ;)

```
Sub Test_Gring()
Dim wB As Workbook, _
    wS As Worksheet, _
    pC As PivotCache, _
    pT As PivotTable, _
    bCreated As Boolean

For Each wS In wB.Sheets
    For Each pT In wS.PivotTables
        If Not bCreated Then
            pT.ChangePivotCache wB.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                                      SourceData:="'Sheet Name'!" & Range("Named_Range").Address, _
                                      Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14)   'xlPivotTableVersion12
            Set pC = pT.PivotCache
            bCreated = True
        Else
            If pT.CacheIndex <> pC.Index Then pT.CacheIndex = pC.Index
        End If
    Next pT
Next wS

'Save to delete unused Pivot Caches
wB.Save
End Sub
```